# comma after wh word phrase

Tags: commas

Do we need a comma in the following sentence?

- What encourages me more to do that [**,**] is that I am interested in science.

Comment: Why would you put a comma there? "What encourages me more to do that" is the subject of the sentence. Would you put a comma in "Spot is a dog"? ("Spot, is a dog" would be bizarre.)

Comment: @Robusto But supposing the OP had wanted to say *The fact, which encourages me to act, is that I am interested in science.* No doubt you would agree that are pair of parenthetical commas are not only appropriate but helpful. I take your point entirely about 'Spot is a dog' but short sentences are fine without punctuation. I would even write 'Tiddles the cat died'. But when you have a sentence with a string of nine short words (prepositions, pronouns etc) it would just seem to me to benefit from some punctuation.

Comment: @WS2 **Comments are not for discussion about aspects not in the question,** such as parenthetical phrases. Please desist. (However much I would like to take issue with your point, I won't here.)

Comment: @WS2: In that case you have inserted a non-restrictive relative clause between subject and copula, which would require two commas to set it off. In the original example, nothing comes between subject and copula. Now, you might not need the commas at all if you intended a restrictive relative clause: "The fact that encourages me to act is that . . ." In fact, you probably intend the latter but didn't quite pull it off.

Comment: There are times when one might be glad of a comma: (1) garden path avoidance: What makes me doubt the Government's statement, is false representation in the past. // (2) avoiding fainting through lack of oxygen:  What makes me doubt that the Government's statement paints a true and unbiased picture of the situation actually obtaining in the small isolated mountain villages of the southwestern provinces of Elbonia, is false representation in the past. One can usually find an 'authority' claiming that someone else's 'rule' for comma usage is merely a useful rule of thumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not put a comma there.

The meaning of your sentence is clear, but it would sound more natural to say something like: *My interest in science encourages me to do that even more.*

However, depending on what has gone before, *this* is probably better than *that.* It is hard to say unless we know more about what you have written before this sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The advice given to me regarding comma usage:  "When in doubt - leave it out".
However, it looks like it would be useful.  If I were you, I would reword the sentence to remove doubt.
"What encourages me more to do that [,] is that I am interested in science."
"I am interested in science and that is why I am encouraged"

Comment: It would not be useful. In this case, it would be confusing.